# Cannot find node-gyp

Tags: node.js, installation, npm, homebrew, node-gyp

I installed node v0.8.22 with homebrew. I have my node binary in `/usr/local/bin/` but I need to recompile a node add-on with `node-gyp` but it cannot seem to find it in my `PATH`. I tried running `npm install -g node-gyp` but it's still not in my path.

I noticed that npm -g installs everything into `/usr/local/share/npm/bin/`. Does this mean I need to add this to my `PATH`?

Comment: is node-gyp deprecated?

Comment: nope nvm, im thinking of node-waf

Comment: where do you expect npm to be?

Comment: Try `sudo npm install node-gyp`. The usage of sudo is generally not recommended unless you are installing a global module.

Comment: @j_mcnally I'm expecting homebrew to handle npm for me

Comment: @j_mcnally `/usr/local/bin/npm`

Comment: that is correct for homebrew

Comment: can you confirm `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` is in path?

Comment: @j_mcnally it's not, should I add it?

Comment: Homebrew installed npm.
We recommend prepending the following path to your PATH environment
variable to have npm-installed binaries picked up:
  /usr/local/share/npm/bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As j_mcnally recommends, you should try adding `/usr/local/share/npm/bin/` to your path. There should be a symlink to `node-gyp` here, which *should* resolve your problem.

Comment: I have the same problem and the question is how to add it to the PATH?!

Comment: @emab - That depends on your OS. On a unix-based system you would probably want to modify your profile script to do something like `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/...`

Answer (score 4):

> I noticed that npm -g installs everything into
>   /usr/local/share/npm/bin/. Does this mean I need to add this to my
>   PATH?

Yes.