# NodeJS npm install pg failed

Tags: node.js, installation, npm, gyp

Im trying to npm install pg on my ubuntu virtual machine and i got error:

```
> pg@1.1.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/core/node_modules/pg
> node-gyp rebuild || (exit 0)

gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/core/node_modules/pg) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:431:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-12-generic
gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/core/node_modules/pg
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.15
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.9
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0


nodejs -v
v0.10.15
npm -v
1.2.18
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Your binding.gyp is missing somehow. Did you try to reinstall it ?

Comment: Could you show us your `$PATH`? Also, please see this [relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15528783/2137601).

Comment: echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: sudo apt-get install libpq-dev helped :) Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I have installed libpq-dev library

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

it helped ;)

Comment: This works. OP, please accept this as the answer for others benefit.

Comment: Please put some explanation in this answer.

Answer (score 11):

Try to install node-gyp first into the global scope?

```
sudo npm -g install node-gyp
```

You should get a result (after all the tgz's are pulled in) that looks like this

```
/usr/local/bin/node-gyp -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
node-gyp@0.12.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp
├── osenv@0.0.3
├── graceful-fs@2.0.1
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── which@1.0.5
├── rimraf@2.2.5
├── semver@2.2.1
├── npmlog@0.0.6 (ansi@0.2.1)
├── nopt@2.1.2 (abbrev@1.0.4)
├── glob@3.2.7 (inherits@2.0.1)
├── fstream@0.1.25 (inherits@2.0.1)
├── minimatch@0.2.12 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── tar@0.1.19 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.7)
└── request@2.29.0 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, forever-agent@0.5.0, aws-sign2@0.5.0, qs@0.6.6, tunnel-agent@0.3.0, oauth-sign@0.3.0, node-uuid@1.4.1, mime@1.2.11, tough-cookie@0.9.15, http-signature@0.10.0, hawk@1.0.0, form-data@0.1.2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try running the following commands and then run npm install, this will take the node's default node-gyp module. (No need to have multiple as node package already provides that)

## Updating the node & NPM

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 4.4.5
sudo npm install npm -g
```

## Removing additional Node-gyp module

```
sudo npm uninstall node-gyp -g
sudo npm uninstall node-gyp
```

Comment: Is the package `n` an alias for node?