# when trying to configure or rebuild node-gyp, getting errors: mac osx mavericks

Tags: macos, node.js, osx-mavericks, node-gyp

I'm trying to run `node-gyp configure`, but am getting the following errors:

```
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /usr/local/bin)
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:337:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "configure"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/bin
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.20
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I think that I'm in the wrong directory, but I'm not sure. Which directory should I be in to run this?

Comment: `node-gyp configure build` is used to build your package which has c/c++ files. You can `cd` to package folder where has a file `binding.gyp` then type `node-gyp configure build` or `node-gyp rebuild`

Comment: Make sure you have the developer tools installed through xcode.

Comment: i have the same problem too, 

in my case i forgot to change the file name from `binding.gyp.txt` to `binding.gyp`, maybe that can help you

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to run `node-gyp rebuild` in current working directory (CWD) `/usr/local/bin` so the `node-gyp` can not find binding at `/usr/local/bin/binding.gyp`.

Navigate your terminal to a directory which contains NodeJS module and only then run `node-gyp rebuild`.

```
cd ~/Projects/your-nodejs-native-module/
node-gyp rebuild
```

BTW I am not sure from which node version exactly but in modern versions, you can just run `npm install` in this directory and npm will run `node-gyp rebuild` for you.

```
cd ~/Projects/your-nodejs-native-module/
npm install
```

Comment: Running `node-gyp rebuild` kept failing for me, but a full `npm install` made the job

Answer (score 1):

if in doubt first re-install `npm install -g node-gyp`.

It's best practice to run `node-gyp rebuild`. Run it from your project's root. Also your `binding.gyp` should be in the root, pointing to dependencies (somewhere else).

In general there shouldn't be any need to run `node-gyp configure` manually.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of the things (not 100% sure) `/usr/local/bin` does not exist in your computer. But it is hard to say from the stack-trace.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with newer versions of node. My best work around has been using something like node version manager (nvm) to revert back to an older version of node and then running `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0):

Install node-gyp globally first:

```
sudo npm -g install node-gyp
```

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20533103/2990066)

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue while working on Angular 10 project on macOS Big Sur 11.5.1

This answer on stack overflow solved it for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55590251/10622142

1. Delete package-lock.json
2. Run command => npm install

Comment: This answer is exactly the same as [another you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68736767/14267427). If you think this question is a duplicate, suggest a duplicate.

Comment: @Tyler2P What exactly do you mean by "suggest a duplicate"?
Do you mean give the link to the other thread and say this is a duplicate of that here?