# binding.gyp not found (c:\xampp\htdocs\webapp) while trying to load binding.gyp in windows XAMPP

Tags: node.js, xampp

I'm trying to rebuild my node-gyp in my xampp htdocs folder, and when the process is running,I got the following errors :
[image]

I have read these pages :

- [node-gyp build error windows x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562038/node-gyp-build-error-windows-x64)
- [when trying to configure or rebuild node-gyp, getting errors: mac osx mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911930/when-trying-to-configure-or-rebuild-node-gyp-getting-errors-mac-osx-mavericks)
- https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/702
- https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/wiki/Updating-npm's-bundled-node-gyp

But the error is still there... Any ideas..?? thank you so much... :)

Note : 
I'm using windows 7 x64

Comment: I've the same issue when I try to run node-gyp configure