# GYP ERR! build error. stack Error: 'make' failed with exit code 2

Tags: node.js, npm, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, gyp

I am currently working on a nodejs web application I am having trouble pushing the application online with cloud foundry. I did some research on the errors and it seems that maybe some of the packages being installed have some conflicts.

This is the package.json file.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "c3": "^0.4.12",
    "cfenv": "1.0.0",
    "cloudant": "^1.8.0",
    "dygraphs": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "4.5.1",
    "getmac": "1.0.6",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "mqtt": "1.0.5",
    "properties": "1.2.1",
    "save": "^2.3.0",
    "sockjs": "0.3.9",
    "websocket-multiplex": "0.1.x"
  },
  "description": "description.",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "main": "app.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "<gitUrl>"
  }
}
```

This is the error I encounter when I try to push the application via cloud foundry. This similar error happens when I npm install after deleting all the content of the **node_modules** folder.

```
../src/bufferutil.cc:32:50: error: call of overloaded 'NODE_SET_METHOD(v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>&, const char [6], void (&)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&))' is ambiguous
     NODE_SET_METHOD(t, "merge", BufferUtil::Merge);

../src/bufferutil.cc:32:50: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:8:0:
/root/.node-gyp/8.0.0/include/node/node.h:257:13: note: void node::NODE_SET_METHOD(v8::Local<v8::Template>, const char*, v8::FunctionCallback)
 inline void NODE_SET_METHOD(v8::Local<v8::Template> recv,
             ^
/root/.node-gyp/8.0.0/include/node/node.h:270:13: note: void node::NODE_SET_METHOD(v8::Local<v8::Object>, const char*, v8::FunctionCallback)
 inline void NODE_SET_METHOD(v8::Local<v8::Object> recv,
             ^
bufferutil.target.mk:95: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/WibiSmart-Bluemix-App/node_modules/bufferutil/build'

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:285:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.30-ti-r64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/WibiSmart-Bluemix-App/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v8.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Did anyone else encounter this issue, or knows how to fix it?

Comment: Whenever you encounter such errors, the *actual* error(s) will appear *before* these lines you've currently posted *in the console*.

Comment: @mscdex I added the lines of code I am getting before the error

Comment: Does switching to node v6 help?

Comment: @opiethehokie What would be the command to do so? It seems to me that the **bufferutil** comes up a lot, would anyone know what that is?

Comment: What is your compiler and compiler version?

Comment: For Mac OS Catalina, downgrading to Node 10.x solved my problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Figured out the issue. Some of the npm packages were not up to date. I modified the package.json to install all the latest versions of all packages and the error was fixed.

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: yes, how to check peer dependencies of libraries and update safely ?

Comment: you may try yarn-check  package it is very helpful

Comment: What if that is not an option?

Comment: Then that is not an option.

Answer (score 162):

> It worked after **deleting** `package-lock.json` and re run `npm
>   install`
>
> If you are using yarn to build your program **delete** `yarn.lock` and
>   re run `yarn install`

Comment: I hate it when this is the solution

Comment: This worked for. In my case it was `yarn.lock` file which I had to delete.

Comment: yes.. if you use yarn to build instead of npm. I'll update my answer.. thank you

Comment: npm upgrade should update all packages to latest. See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-update or https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-upgrade

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg I hate it much more when this ISN'T the solution.

Comment: Holy crap, can't believe it was as simple as that!!

Comment: What this is most likely doing is the same thing as a npm upgrade, I think. You could try upgrading bcrypt, if you depend on it directly.

Comment: Do me a big fever

Answer (score 50):

In our case (since `make` failed), this issue could be resolved by **installing the build / development tools**:

Ubuntu / Debian:

```
apt-get install -y build-essential
```

CentOS:

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ make
```

Fedora 23 and above:

```
dnf install @development-tools
```

macOS:

```
xcode-select --install
```

If this is not the solution, you might want to try to upgrade or downgrade node, remove `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules` folder, and then re-run `npm install`.

Comment: How to do this for mac?

Comment: For now I'm trying this..not a huge fan of homebrew or ruby, but if it works.... https://docs.macstadium.com/docs/install-osx-build-tools

Comment: Xcode is installed. I am running on MacOS 11.4 - I'm wondering if I'll be forced to update the system before I can move forward with this issue. Unfortunately my internet is garbage and it's an 8GB download - which always fails a GB or 2 into the download, and then wants to start over again from the beginning. Any idea if this is critical to making it work?

Comment: @John I don't expect you need to update macOS. Did you also install the Command Line Tools for Xcode?

Comment: That's it. After two days I stumbled here. Solved for Ubuntu 22.04.1 (same solutions in 3 different machines)

Comment: fixed my problem on ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 26):

This has been old yet consistent issue well documented at: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809

For me the error mentioned the version numbers like:

```
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! node -v v12.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
```

After attempting all the possible combinations of solutions (modify `~/.npmrc`, remove `~/.node-gyp`, clear the npm cache, delete `node_modules` and even restart the system), what worked with me was downgrading the node.

I believe the versions mentioned in the log for `node` and `node-gyp` are incompatible. So I reverted to an older node version which worked like a charm.

```
npm install -g node@11.10.0
```

There should be a clear documentation describing breaking changes and compatibility issues between the two.

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for for 3 days!! Although I was experiencing the problem inside a Docker container (rather than on a host machine), it does sound like I've been down the same route as you - trying to re-install node, clearing caches etc.  For me, basing the container on `node:current-alpine` was the mistake (version 16 at time of writing).  Changing to `node:12.2.0-alpine` fixed my problem and allowed `npm install` complete. I suspect that the underlying reason for my resolution is the same as yours -- the older Docker container essentially downgrades the version of node.

Comment: How can one check if a specific version of `node-gyp` is a compatible with a specific version of `node`?

Comment: This works for me. Additional resources to the answer: (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-node-version#answer-50287454 (2) https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Comment: For me I down graded to version 14 from version 16 of node and the issue went away.

Answer (score 15):

For other people that stumble into this exact problem:

In my case, the server node version was set to an older version in my package.json file than what my local environment was running.
So check what you are running locally with:

```
node --version
-> 8.11.3
```

Then look at your server setting in your package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.10.2" // <-- This is too old, set it to the node version you are running locally (8.11.3)
  },
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This solved it for me. Downgraded from Node 10 to Node 8 and got my repo running locally.

Comment: I don't have anything like `"engines": {
    "node": "7.10.2"locally (8.11.3)
  },` in my package.json. Can't figure out what version of Node it think it is

Answer (score 15):

In my case, it was cased by node-sass(version < 6.0.1) not supporting Node 16. Update node-sass to 6.0.1 and the issue is solved. see [error: no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'remove_cv'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67241196/error-no-template-named-remove-cv-t-in-namespace-std-did-you-mean-remove/67303155#67303155).

One learning to my experience is that you should read the error messages very carefully and search the "root cause message". In my case it was `error: no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'remove_cv'?`. It showed right above the `GYP ERR! build error. stack Error: 'make' failed with exit code 2` line.

Answer (score 9):

Delete the ~/.node-gyp folder and then the ~/.npmrc file.

Reboot your server and rerun npm install in your project folder

**Edit:**

Warning: removing ~/.npmrc will delete your other configurations

Comment: Warning: removing `~/.npmrc` will delete your other configurations, for example your default author name.

Answer (score 4):

I think delete this directory and clean the cache of `npm`  is better:

```
rm -rf ~/.node-gyp/
rm -r node_modules/.bin/;
rm -r build/
npm cache clean
```

and you can test

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

and

```
npm install -g node-pre-gyp
```

finally:

```
npm install <your module>
```

Answer (score 4):

In Linux it is fixed by installing build essential
`sudo apt-get install build-essential`
but in my Windows wsl2
installing only the build-essential did not solve the issue,
I have to downgrade the node to 16.15.0 then it got resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this while building the image based on `node:alipine`.

Since my Dockerfile didn't specify the version, the latest one was used, which is Node 16 published 3 days ago at Docker Hub.

Downgrading it to 15 (`node:15-alpine`) solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), you can also change to the version your package supports, like:

```
nvm install 7.10.2
nvm use 7.10.2
```

Answer (score 2):

change Node version from 16.15.1 to 14.17.3

```
 sudo n 14.17.3
```

Comment: This worked for me. `npm install` failed in my project. I saw a recommendation to upgrade it and did it. I had npm 16.15.1. `npm install` failed again. Cleaning caches did not help. Downgrading npm and cleaning caches helped. Command I used `npm install -g node@14.17.3 --force`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but didn't realise it was being caused by an error further up in the logs. `python` was not installed correctly.

```
env: python: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/sass.a] Error 127
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/private/var/folders/5q/3y3xtdk11g11sgclgtc6vtvh0000gn/T/xfs-b4670056/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when installed the gazebo gzweb. I found out that `apt install nodejs` install the "node" in the direction of "/usr/bin/". You can verify by `which node`. But `node -v` is still referring to "/usr/local/bin/node" which is a wrong version I failed to uninstall. 
Thus as my solution:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node
cp -i /usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/
cp -i /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/
```

Steps:

`sudo apt-get install npm
npm install -g n
n stable
npm install npm@6.9.0 -g
ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm`

Answer (score 0):

### CentOS 6 users

Node 10+ requires GCC4.9. And apparently CentOS 6 doesn't have it. You can use these commands before npm install as a workaround (tested with Node 11 NPM 6).

```
yum install devtoolset-7
source scl_source enable devtoolset-7
```

Source: https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1283

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to resolve the issue.

#### Debug #1: Deleting package-lock.json file

```
rm -rf package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules

npm install
```

#### Debug #2: Deleting .node-gyp folder

```
rm -rf ~/.node-gyp

npm install
```

#### Debug #3: Re-install node-gyp

```
npm i -g node-gyp
```

#### Debug #4: Install build essentials

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Source: https://codeforgeek.com/make-failed-with-exit-code-2/

Comment: please update your answer with corresponding commands

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04. I tried all the solutions mentioned here and nothing worked. The actual problem is versioning difference. I am sure the same `package.json` will be working fine on one of your team mate's local machine. You just need to ask your team mates about which npm and node version they are using and install it on your local machine.

To install specific version of npm:

```
sudo npm install -g npm@specific_npm_version_here
```

To install specific version of node:

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n specify_node_version_here
```

Comment: Please don't post the same answer to multiple questions. They will get flagged for deletion and, if multiple questions have the same answer you should consider flagging those questions as duplicates rather than repeating your answer.

Comment: @DavidBuck Thanks for pointing this out. I was not aware of it. The motive is to provide correct solution.

Comment: Understood. [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292331/7508700) has some helpful advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading this after December 16th 2021, you may have been seeing build errors due to a Heroku node version upgrade issue.

As per the Heroku changelog:

> Ruby apps now default to Node version 16.13.1 and Yarn version 1.22.17
> Change effective on 16 December 2021
>
> Applications using the heroku/ruby buildpack that do not have a
> version of Node installed by another buildpack (such as the
> heroku/nodejs buildpack) will now receive:
>
> Node version 16.13.1 (was previously 12.16.2) Yarn version 1.22.17
> (was previously 1.22.4)

https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2306

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error, and for me the solution was to downgrade the node version.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the project depends on older node version. Ask the owner about appropriate version or make a try with 'nvm install

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me and seems as the right solution i did not found here is replacing `node-sass` which is deprecated to the `sass` library
i used this guide: https://dev.to/ccreusat/migrating-from-node-sass-to-sass-dart-sass-with-npm-3g3c
basically change the library:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "version_installed"
}
```

to

```
"devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.49.9"
}
```

and change the sass commands somewhat like so (package.json):

```
"scripts": {
 "build-sass": "node-sass --output-style compressed <css dist> <scss source files>"
}
```

to:

```
"scripts": {
 "build-sass": "sass --style=compressed <css dist> <scss source files>"
}
```

Comment: It would be ideal to quote the relevant part of the links here in case it's inaccessible in the future. In short, explain how to make the switch of libraries.

Comment: @mozway is that looks better?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this topic,but it looks like it. Thanks. I'll let specialists vote on this.