# gyp rebuild fails and linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: node.js, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

im trying to npm install in react native project but i get this error

```
> weak@1.0.1 install /Users/jopp/Projects/jopp/node_modules/weak
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/weakref/src/weakref.o
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'iPhoneSimulator' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/weakref.node
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'iPhoneSimulator' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]
ld: building for OSX, but linking against dylib built for iOS (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.2.sdk/usr/lib/libc++.tbd). file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.2.sdk/usr/lib/libc++.tbd' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/weakref.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/jopp/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/jopp/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.1/bin/node" "/Users/jopp/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jopp/Projects/jopp/node_modules/weak
gyp ERR! node -v v7.10.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

everything is ok on android but cant run ios on simulator

- OS : macOS High Sierra
- node: 7.10
- node-gyp: 3.5
- npm: 4.2

Comment: Uh, start here?  clang: warning: using sysroot for 'iPhoneSimulator' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316064/gyp-err-build-error-stack-error-make-failed-with-exit-code-2

Answer (score -4):

restarting your machine should solve it