# Process exited with code 2 while debug in nodejs vscode

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have nodejs project that I want to run in debug mode in VSCode

Here is the Project structure

```
.vscode
  - launch.json
services
  - user
     - server.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
tslint.json
```

and here is the package.json scripts tag

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "del-cli ./dist/*",
    "prestart": "yarn clean && tsc",
    "start": "yarn serve",
    "serve": "node dist/server.js",
    "start-dev": "yarn prestart && concurrently \"tsc --watch \" \"nodemon dist/server.js\""
},
```

and the **launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "runtimeArgs": ["run-script","prestart"],
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is showing

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd run-script prestart

> myproj@1.0.0 prestart C:\PERSONAL\projects\myproj
> yarn clean && tsc && yarn copyfiles

c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:255

c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:71
Process exited with code 2
```

**Update 1**

it was raising issue because invalid path in tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "./**/*"
    ]
}
```

I updated **include** from `src/**/*` to `./**/*`.

Now it compiling the typescript files but still exist with code 2.

Comment: Please check is this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316064/gyp-err-build-error-stack-error-make-failed-with-exit-code-2

Comment: It would help if you share the an example of code with the commands you typed so that others can run them in their local. 
@VarunJain shared link might have the answer.
Probably your Node.js and npm version mismatch would be one of the potential reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found

```
An error code (also exit code) of 2 means "File not found"
```

In my case, project contains multiple sub projects. The dependency is mentioned in package.json but it was not installed somehow, so by running

```
npm install
```

command, worked for me.