# npm install pg gets killed on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, postgresql, npm

I have been trying to install node-postgres package in my nodejs application.

https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres

But I am getting following error all the times. It gets killed.

```
root@MyUbuntu:~/MyProject# npm install pg --save
Killed     ........] \ loadExtraneous: verb afterAdd /root/.npm/through/2.3.8/package/package.json written
```

I have seen other similar questions but they are not related to my specific problem. I was able to install other packages in the same project, it means npm is working fine.

I looked into following questions as well:

[NodeJS npm install pg failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972402/nodejs-npm-install-pg-failed)

Comment: [OOM killer](https://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer)?

Comment: The memory of my droplet is 512 MB. should I increase the RAM?

Comment: Check system logs (using `dmesg` or `tail -100 /var/log/syslog`) to make sure it's the OOM killer. If so, then you're probably going to need more RAM.

Comment: I found following log `Out of memory: Kill process 5696`. I think I should increase the RAM. Thanks.